# How come a returned string can be interpreted as a function in python? 

Tags: python, string, function

I was skimming through `Learn python the hard way` and I have come across a code snippet like below. But I did not understand what's behind it, a function basically returns a string that which it's class has a function of the same name. And it can call the function properly. 
Well, you will get what I mean when you look at the code.

### Code:

```
from sys import exit
class Game(object):
    def __init__(self, start):
        self.start = start

    def play(self):
        next = self.start

        while True:
            print "\n--------"
            room = getattr(self, next)
            next = room()

    def a1(self):
        print "You are in a1, redirecting to a2"
        return 'a2'
    def a2(self):
        print "You are in a2, exiting"
        return 'death'
    def death(self):
        print 'You died'
        exit(0)


a_game = Game('a1')
a_game.play()
```

Comment: Did you read about `getattr()` function yet?  What confused you about how that function works?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you see is the result of the `getattr()` builtin. Python is a high level language and what's more, an interpreted one. Since all objects in python are basically constructed in memory in forms of hash-tables Python has a rather vast [Reflection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_%28computer_programming%29) mechanism.

This means that Python can inspect and modify its own classes and objects in **runtime** and one of the ways to do so is the `getattr()` builtin.
The `getattr` builtin retrieves the *value* of the member in the first argument, which *name* it receives as a *string* in the second argument. `getattr(x, "y")` is basically the same as `x.y`, but `getattr` also allows for a safer approach where a default value can be given if a member is not actually present: `getattr(x, "y", "No such member")`. If `x` has no member `y` then `x.y` would cause an `AttributeError` exception. On the other hand `gettattr(x, "y", "No such member")` would return the string "No such member" and no exception is raised.

In your case, the methods are placed in the `next` variable as strings and are accessed through the `getattr()` builtin placed into `room`. `room()` is then invoked and the next methods name is returned and stored into `next`. This repeats in the `while` loop until `exit(0)` is invoked in `Game.death()`.

You should also have a look at `setattr()` and `hasattr()`

Answer (score 4):

The trick is the `getattr` function. It gets an attribute from an object, given its name. The name is a string. the names of the methods (bound functions) are passed as the `next` variable, getattr gets the method, and the next line calls it, changing the next variable. It's basically a state machine.